# java.io.IOException: Invalid file path while creating and writing in a File

Tags: java, file, java-io, ioexception

I am trying to create a file inside a directory but when the code executes it brings back the error `'java.io.IOException: Invalid file path'`. 
And the code does create the directory called 'ServerUploads' but **it does not create the file**. 
Below is a code snippet :

```
   public static String performUploadOperation(byte[] file, String filename)
        throws IOException {
    //creating a directory to store file.
    //creating a directory to store users
    File userDirectory = new File("C:\\ServerUploads");
    //check if directory does not exist.
    if (!userDirectory.exists()) {
        userDirectory.mkdir();
    }


        File crreate = new File(userDirectory + "\\" +  filename);

        if(!crreate.exists())
        crreate.createNewFile();




    try{
    //convert the bytearray retrieved to a file and upload to server folder.
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(crreate);
   System.out.println(fos.toString());
        //write file to directory.
        fos.write(file);
        fos.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sucess = "600 - The file has been successfully uploaded!";
    return sucess;
}
```

The filename being passed as argument is **'upload.txt'** . I am not sure why it is not working. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!.
Please see I need the method to `return` a `String` not a `void` as I have to further `return` it to the client.

Comment: Hi, can you try switching `\\` to `/` in your file constructor? also, what is the byte array for?

Comment: I have updated my code with the full method and the forward slash did not work unfortunately.

Comment: @GavinEverett Your code is working apart from `return sucess;` where it should be either `String sucess =....` or directly `return "600 - The file has been successfully uploaded!"` .Can you add your complete exception from console and how you're calling `performUploadOperation(..,...)`

Comment: The `createNewFile()` call here is a waste of time and space, as are both `exists()` calls.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution to the problem. The solution was to add '.trim()' to the filename string. There must have been some white-space when the file came in.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Good, as I said your code was working only part we would like to see was how you're calling `performUploadOperation(.. , ..)` and thus eventually what you're passing in  `file`  and  `filename` ! So lesson learnt right? Next time lets add more context/relevance over SO in question and save everyone's time. : )

Answer (score -1):

I tried following code block by just changing return type `String` to `void` as nothing was returned. It worked. The folder & file both get created.
Here is the code block for same:

```
public static void performUploadOperation(byte[] file, String filename)
        throws IOException {
    //creating a directory to store file.
    //creating a directory to store users
    File userDirectory = new File("C:\\ServerUploads");
    //check if directory does not exist.
    if (!userDirectory.exists()) {
        userDirectory.mkdir();
    }
    File crreate = new File(userDirectory + "\\" + filename);

    if (!crreate.exists())
        crreate.createNewFile();
}
```

Calling above function from main:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    performUploadOperation("abc".getBytes(),"testfile");
}
```

Comment: you missed to give variable type. It should be `String sucess =` not just `sucess =`. Also the content of file will not get printed in the way you wrote your `System.out.println(fos.toString());`

It should be replaced with : 
            `ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            stream.write(file);
            System.out.println(new String(stream.toByteArray()));`

Comment: There is nothing here that solves or even identifies the problem.

Comment: The issue was `java.io.IOException: Invalid file path` given by code posted & the answer I posted solves this problem. When I ran this program on my m/c it didn't gave any error.